# Function call not displaying undefined value when an array is passed as param

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, parameters, parameter-passing

I have created the following function in JavaScript which is working as expected:

```
<script>
    function add(a, b, c) {
        document.write('A: ' + a + '<br>');
        document.write('B: ' + b + '<br>');
        document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
    }
add(10, 20);
</script>
```

### Output:

```
A: 10
B: 20
C: undefined
```

However, the following function in JavaScript is not working as expected wherein it is not displaying `undefined` value

```
<script>
    function addArray(a = [101]) {
        document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
        document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
        document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
    }
    addArray([110]);
</script>
```

### Output:

```
A: 110
B: 110
```

As per my understanding the output should be as below:

### Expected Output:

```
A: 110
B: 110
C: undefined
```

Also, what is difference between `a[0]` and `a` in the above example?

Comment: `c` is *undeclared*, you should be getting a ReferenceError in the console.

Comment: check your console, it will be throwing errors for that

Comment: To see the difference between `a[0]` and `a`, try `addArray([110, 111])`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the difference is with `c`

Comment: @VLAZ Since you already addressed that, I was answering the last line of the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

c is never declared

```js
    function addArray(a=[101],c) {
        document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
        document.write('B: ' + a + '<br>');
        document.write('C: ' + c + '<br>');
    }
    addArray([110,120]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 The difference between a[0] and a is that a[0] is displaying the first index value of an 
 array and a is displaying all the values of the array.

 Imagine A=[100,200]
 document.write('A: ' + a[0] + '<br>');
 Would write 100
 document.write('A: ' + a + '<br>');
 Would write 100,200
```